# Add facet to primefaces panel from bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

```
<h:form>
    <p:dashboard id="board"
    binding="#{fundamentFormCreatorBean.dashboard}">
    </p:dashboard>
</h:form>    

 FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            Application application = fc.getApplication();
            dashboard = (Dashboard) application.createComponent(fc,
                    "org.primefaces.component.Dashboard",
                    "org.primefaces.component.DashboardRenderer");
            dashboard.setId("dashboard");
            DashboardModel model = new DefaultDashboardModel();
                column1 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();
            Panel panel = (Panel) application.createComponent(fc,
                    "org.primefaces.component.Panel",
                    "org.primefaces.component.PanelRenderer");
            panel.setId("UniqueId");
            panel.setHeader("panelName");
            panel.setClosable(true);
            dashboard.getChildren().add(panel);
            column1.addWidget(panel.getId());
```

I want to add a `f:facet` to a panel from bean.I have added **Primefaces dashboard** and its panels dynamically from bean shown in the above code. I tried to add a facet with the below code but didn't work out.

```
 HtmlGraphicImage oTabImage= new HtmlGraphicImage();                         
 oTabImage.setValue("/images/tabicon.jpg");                            
 HtmlOutputText oText = new HtmlOutputText();
 oText.setValue("Here is my label");                               
 HtmlPanelGroup oGroup = new HtmlPanelGroup();
 oGroup.getChildren().add(oText);
 oGroup.getChildren().add(oTabImage);   
 panel.getFacets().put("label", oGroup);
```

Comment: Did you try to add a `ui:debug` to your page and check if it is in the view?

Comment: You are unnecessarily trying to achieve the goal in both of your questions using verbose Java code which can easily be achieved using XHTML.

Comment: @Tiny , I know it is easy to achieve with XHTML, but I need to generate dynamic forms so I need a mechanism to create ui from the bean code.

Comment: What Tiny means is that even the dynamic part can be achieved with xhtml... There is **nothing** in your example that **requires** it to be done in java. And Try one in xhtml. I think it will fail to... Check the documentation and showcase... and focus on the facet

Comment: @Kukeltje I only have dashboard tag in XHTML, If it possible to add facets to panels of dashboard dynamically through XHTML  Please let me know.

Comment: Putting "label" facet to a panel won't achieve anything because panel (PrimeFaces one) doesn't have such facet. Try getting children (`panel.getChildren()`) of a panel and add new children (html element, UIComponent). This way you can add content to the panel. If you really want to add a facet then add valid one: footer/header/options/actions.

Answer (score 0):

The PrimeFaces panel does not have the label facet. So this will never work, not even in xhtml (as stated by me). Try the [header facet](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf#346), that will work